# How does boastful attitide on a job interview help interviewers and companies?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, company-culture

I've heard on some job interviews a lot of technical interviewers showing excessive bragging and very questionable claims like:

> "We are proactive. I mastered Terraform in two days."

> "Our team learns all the time. This summer due to the pandemic I didn't
> travel and studied to level up."

> "We have top-notch people coming from Google and Facebook, expect to be
> on their level and to push hard."

These are claims from the technical interviewers, not from HR. Also from different companies but not startups. I believe this is something aligned with the management - some template to show competency.

How is excessive bragging beneficial to interviewing? Does it translate to bad culture or it's a marketing approach that should be ignored?

Comment: Those comments don't sound like excessive bragging. Saying you spent the summer studying is hardly akin to claiming to be the second coming of Jesus Christ, and saying you have people coming from Google or Facebook may or may not be factual. Would you take a job with a company where everyone said "We're kinda shit"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: I *think* it's most likely a sales pitch, directed by management.

I do a lot of technical interviews, exactly for infrastructure (although we don't use terraform). Finding good people with experience is nearly impossible. Finding average people is pretty hard. So management might encourage you to sell a bit harder, especially if you are short-handed.

I'm usually honest during the interviews, I got good people on my team now, I had bad people in the past, we are evolving, some procedures are boring, I can be *very* annoying, and so on. But I do understand the motivation for trying to paint a nicer picture.

The problem I see with that approach is that it falls apart quickly. My guess is that in the same way I can see through most of the boastful candidates, a good candidate will be able to see through a boastful interviewer. Then the boasts become a bit of a red flag.

However, I can only be this honest because that's my manager's attitude as well, he's technical enough that you can't fake it with him, and it is funny to see people try.

It doesn't matter how good they say they are, when we get to the meat of the technical, there is no faking it :)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with inferring that the company is used to dealing with high-caliber employees.  Often, candidates will have some gauge of their own competency.  If the interviewer says (for example) our average developer is a "9" and the candidate knows he or she is a 6, it *could* be better on everyone's time and emotions if the candidate declines the interview.  On the other hand, certain candidates will be more open to such a challenge.

The bottom line is that the statements you mentioned mean "we don't just hire any old kind of person here!!!"  Go big, or go home.

Comment: Every company thinks they hire the best, or at least says they do. I've heard companies say that who in fact have below average people and high turnover.